# Azure Pipeline flutter command in Command Line Script

Tags: flutter, azure, cmd

I am trying to build and deploy a Flutter Web App using Azure Dev Ops.
I set up a pipeline with Flutter Install and Flutter Build. Before I build the app, I want to run a command line script for some configurations. In the end of the script, I want to run `flutter pub run build_runner build` for the code generator. But I need to configure the flutter command, and I don't know how. Otherwise, the output is `command not found: flutter`

Here a screenshot of my pipeline:
[image: Pipeline]

At first I thought the Flutter Install task would already fix that. But it doesn't. Does someone know what I need to configure in order to run the flutter command?

Answer (score -1):

This is the way I deployed my flutter web app into the Azure static web app:

- get flutter tasks from [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Hey24sheep.flutter)
- use this yaml file to deploy to deploy the flutter app into Azure Static web app:
- Do not forget to set a variable for Static web app token

```
trigger:
  - http-request

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - task: Hey24sheep.flutter.flutter-install.FlutterInstall@0
    displayName: 'Flutter Install'
  
  - task: Hey24sheep.flutter.flutter-command.FlutterCommand@0
    displayName: 'Flutter Command'
    inputs:
      projectDirectory: app
      arguments: 'config --enable-web'


  - task: Hey24sheep.flutter.flutter-command.FlutterCommand@0
    displayName: 'flutter run build web'
    inputs:
      projectDirectory: app #{here put your source code folder}
      arguments: 'build web'

  - task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
    displayName: "web"
    inputs:
      app_location: "app" #{here put your source code folder}
      api_location: ""
      # app_build_command: "flutter build web"
      app_build_command: ""
      output_location: "build/web"
    env:
      azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(deployment-token-development)
```